# How to debug Linux server connection silence

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ping, netstat

[EDIT]
After I restarted for the 6th time it finally worked. I have no clue why, but hey, I can proceed again.
[/EDIT]

I'm developing a website using the Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Flask comes with a convenient built in development server which works on port 5000. Until today I was happily developing on a remote (aws) Ubuntu 14.04 server and I could just open the website in the browser using the direct ip and the port (http://52.xx.xx.xx:5000).

This worked great, but after I started the dev-server today I can't reach the website from the browser anymore. I made sure the dev server is indeed running and listening on port 5000. I also checked using netstat (see the listening python process on port 5000):

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      969/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10843           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1913/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1913/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      960/mongod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1092/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      982/redis-server 12
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      969/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18825           0.0.0.0:*                           607/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           607/dhclient
udp6       0      0 :::13841                :::*                                607/dhclient
```

So I tried pinging the server:

```
$ ping 52.xx.xx.xx
PING 52.xx.xx.xx (52.xx.xx.xx): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
etc.
```

So `ssh` works, but my dev server and pinging doesn't work.

And from this point I'm kinda lost. Does anybody know what the next steps are to debug this? All tips are welcome!

(ps. I'm more a programmer than a sysadmin, so please excuse my ignorance.)

[EDIT]
To answer @MariusMatutiae his questions in the comment. I did restart (multiple times) and the output of `sudo iptables -L -n -v`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

My knowledge kind of ends here. Does this tell you anything?

Comment: Since `ssh` works, check the firewall configuration: `iptables -L -n -v`. And, BTW, did you reboot? Reboot surely solves a lot of partial configuration issues, like yours sounds to be.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - I answered your question in the my question above. Does this tell you anything?

Comment: No, unfortunately the firewall is not the issue. Just to make sure: when you connect via `ssh`, do you use the IP address or the machine name?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - I just restarted one more time and now it suddenly works again. Since I restarted at least 5 times before (also for updates and an unreachable `screen` session) I really do not understand why it does make a difference now. Anyway, thanks for thinking along!